# BlackBerry 10 Simulator screen has inverted and have visual artifacts

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld app on BlackBerry 10 Simulator to get started with BlackBerry 10 development. However, the simulator looks really weird and I cant seem to make any sense of it. Is this how the simulator is supposed to look (screen shot)? How to go about running a BlackBerry 10 app?[image]

Comment: That doesn't look right at all.  I would suggest downloading the simulator again.  The simulator should look exactly like a bb10 phone screen.

Comment: I have already tried downloading the simulator again - I have two simulators installed: `1) BlackBerry 10 Native SDK 10.2.0.1155 and 2) BlackBerry 10 Native SDK 10.2.1.1055`. Both look exactly the same. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Can you describe the environment you are using - OS and level of VM Ware?

Comment: Also does your system match the specs required here: http://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/simulator_systemrequirements.html

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. You should install `VMware Player >=3.1` version. But looks like you installed `2.x` version.